# Angular 6 Unexpected behavior when getting access to child component of a parent component using lazy laoding

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular6

I am working on a registration system using Angular 6.
The base `AppModule` contains the following routes and they are working properly:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
    //canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path:'dashboard',
    loadChildren: '../app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'

  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

As you can see, I am using the lazy loading concept, where I created a new module and component called `dashboard`, containing the routes script `dashboard-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: DashboardComponent,
  },
  {
    path:'home',
    loadChildren: './main-navbar/main-navbar.module#MainNavbarModule'

  },
  {
    path:'**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

As you can see again, I am using lazy loading again inside the dashboard component, and inside of it, I created the final module/component called `main-navbar.component` wherein this part, all other after login component will be executed.

The structure is now like the following:

[image]

Here is a [plunker to check it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzaxuw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts&view=editor).

**And for the simplicity, I removed the login and forgot password components, so you can check the dashboard component directly**.

What's going wrong is described like the following:

When logged in, the user will see the following URL properly with no errors:

`localhost:4200/dashboard`

Where the dashboard contains the component of `main-navbar`:

[image]

[image]

Now I need to display the other components inside this page, so if the URL is:

`localhost:4200/dashboard/home`

I am redirected to the login component and get no errors. I think the problem is in how I am handling the routing files, and where I am putting the `<router-outlet>` elements, but can't figure it out.

Comment: For dashboard route module ts file, you should register the module with 'imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],', pay attention to 'forChild'. I am not sure if you used that or not.

Comment: It does exist in my `dashboard-routing.module.ts` sir. Still can't figure it since 2 days.

Comment: @wannadream can you help me sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in dashboard-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './main-navbar/main-navbar.module#MainNavbarModule'

      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: It redirects me to login component with an error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component DashboardComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

Comment: Import DashboardComponent to entryComponents in app.module.ts.

Comment: I tried with your StackBlitz. It worked. However, I am a little confused. Dashboard --> Main NavBar --> Home ? Are the routes correct?

Comment: Main navbar is a material sidenav design where I added inside dashboard, so the link should be only dashboard/home if I want to go to home component. have you saved the plunker to check it ?

Comment: I don't know why it does not run after I forked the code. Please check the code for idea: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l6mhu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard-routing.module.ts

Comment: It's weird. When I ran it upon editing yours, it worked. However, after I forked it, it does not.

Comment: Exactly that's what is happening.